# How to "tee" NSPipe in Swift

Tags: swift, foundation, tee, darwin, nspipe

I'm trying to tee the standard output NSPipe one of NSTask to get two NSPipes, each of which will go into the standard input of two new NSTasks.

I know I can do this in C with the [`tee` function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/tee.htm), but I couldn't find it in neither the Foundation nor Darwin frameworks. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Then  the best way is to write it in C and use bridging header

Comment: I figure I might do that. Strangely though, I can see other members of the `fcntl.h` header, such as `fcntl()` in the `Darwin` module, but not `tee()`

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, OS X does not have a `tee` system call or library function, only a `/usr/bin/tee` command.

Comment: @MartinR Interesting, so I would have to implement my own with like a `read()`/`write()` loop?

Comment: @MartinR What do you think is the best is to achieve this? (Invoke 2 different NSTasks to work with the input of another NSTask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a solution to this and it is working well in my project. I have made a Swift package available [on GitHub](https://github.com/deatondg/tee.swift). You can also find examples of its use there. Here is the code:

```swift
/**
 Duplicates the data from `input` into each of the `outputs`.
 Following the precedent of `standardInput`/`standardOutput`/`standardError` in `Process` from `Foundation`,
    we accept the type `Any`, but throw a precondition failure if the arguments are not of type `Pipe` or `FileHandle`.
 https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/eec4b26deee34edb7664ddd9c1222492a399d122/Sources/Foundation/Process.swift
 When `input` sends an EOF (write of length 0), the `outputs` file handles are closed, so only output to handles you own.
 This function sets the `readabilityHandler` of inputs and the `writeabilityHandler` of outputs,
    so you should not set these yourself after calling `tee`.
 The one exception to this guidance is that you can set the `readabilityHandler` of `input` to `nil` to stop `tee`ing.
 After doing so, the `writeabilityHandler`s of the `output`s will be set to `nil` automatically after all in-progress writes complete,
    but if desired, you could set them to `nil` manually to cancel these writes. However, this may result in some outputs recieving less of the data than others.
 This implementation waits for all outputs to consume a piece of input before more input is read.
 This means that the speed at which your processes read data may be bottlenecked by the speed at which the slowest process reads data,
    but this method also comes with very little memory overhead and is easy to cancel.
 If this is unacceptable for your use case. you may wish to rewrite this with a data deque for each output.
 */
public func tee(from input: Any, into outputs: Any...) {
    tee(from: input, into: outputs)
}
public func tee(from input: Any, into outputs: [Any]) {
    /// Get reading and writing handles from the input and outputs respectively.
    guard let input = fileHandleForReading(input) else {
        preconditionFailure(incorrectTypeMessage)
    }
    let outputs: [FileHandle] = outputs.map({
        guard let output = fileHandleForWriting($0) else {
            preconditionFailure(incorrectTypeMessage)
        }
        return output
    })
    
    let writeGroup = DispatchGroup()
    
    input.readabilityHandler = { input in
        let data = input.availableData
        
        /// If the data is empty, EOF reached
        guard !data.isEmpty else {
            /// Close all the outputs
            for output in outputs {
                output.closeFile()
            }
            /// Stop reading and return
            input.readabilityHandler = nil
            return
        }
        
        for output in outputs {
            /// Tell `writeGroup` to wait on this output.
            writeGroup.enter()
            output.writeabilityHandler = { output in
                /// Synchronously write the data
                output.write(data)
                /// Signal that we do not need to write anymore
                output.writeabilityHandler = nil
                /// Inform `writeGroup` that we are done.
                writeGroup.leave()
            }
        }
        
        /// Wait until all outputs have recieved the data
        writeGroup.wait()
    }
}

/// The message that is passed to `preconditionFailure` when an incorrect type is passed to `tee`.
let incorrectTypeMessage = "Arguments of tee must be either Pipe or FileHandle."

/// Get a file handle for reading from a `Pipe` or the handle itself from a `FileHandle`, or `nil` otherwise.
func fileHandleForReading(_ handle: Any) -> FileHandle? {
    switch handle {
    case let pipe as Pipe:
        return pipe.fileHandleForReading
    case let file as FileHandle:
        return file
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
/// Get a file handle for writing from a `Pipe` or the handle itself from a `FileHandle`, or `nil` otherwise.
func fileHandleForWriting(_ handle: Any) -> FileHandle? {
    switch handle {
    case let pipe as Pipe:
        return pipe.fileHandleForWriting
    case let file as FileHandle:
        return file
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you aren't supposed to close `FileHandle.standardOutput` and friends, so you will need to modify this code to use them. I have added functionality to control when handles are released to the git repo.